# Expected 2 calls to the destructor but got only 1

Tags: c++, destructor

I was studying how a function returns an object by means of return-by-value. So, to test the theory, I ran a simple program that had a function returning an instance of myclass - a custom-made class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

class myclass {
    int i;
    public:
    void set_i(int n) { i=n; }
    ~myclass();
};

myclass f(int k); // return object of type myclass

int main()
{
    f(20);
    return 0;
}

myclass f(int k)
{
    myclass x;
    x.set_i(k);
    return x;
}

myclass::~myclass() {
cout << "hello\n";
}
```

I overloaded the destructor by placing a cout "hello" statement in it so that I would be able to track when the object's local copy within the function as well as the temporary object created during execution of the return statement were destroyed.

So, I was expected 2 calls to the destructor; one for the function's local copy of the object and one for the temporary object. But instead, I received only one!

Please share why my program did not output "hello" twice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is an effect of **return value optimization** which eliminates the temporary object created to hold a function's return value. This optimizes out the redundant copy constructor and destructor calls.